# HTML elements won't format using classes or IDs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, element

I'm trying to build a single page that just displays a div. When I try to use classes or IDs as selectors, my elements won't format, but when I use the actual element as a selector, it formats just fine.

This is the code I have that won't format the div or the paragraph it contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Placeholder</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color:#9585FF;
}
.centerBox {
    margin:auto;
    width:60%;
    height:1200px;
    background-color:#D6D1F9;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
h1 {
    width:800px;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
    color:white;
    font-size:600%;
    font-family:courier;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#centerText {
    font-size:140%;
    font-color:#000000;
    font-family:courier;
    font-weight:bold;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1><a href="matthew-renze.netau.net">renze</a></h1>
<div id="centerBox">
<p class="centerText">Some text for the center div</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything except the centerDiv id and the centerText class format just fine.
Those only work when I forgo the class/id and just use the element name:

```
.centerBox {
    margin:auto;
    width:60%;
    height:1200px;
    background-color:#D6D1F9;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#centerText {
    font-size:140%;
    font-color:#000000;
    font-family:courier;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I realize this is just fine for what I have posted, but it'll screw me up if I try to add more divs or paragraphs. Likely I made a noob mistake, but help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The problem in your CSS is that you have `#centerText` which is an ID and `.centerBox` which is a class. In your HTML they are opposite. Your CSS should be `#centerBox` and `.centerText`

Comment: You've got the `#` and `.` prefixes back to front. `#` are for IDs, `.` for classes.

Comment: `.` represents class and `#` represents ID. fyi ID should be unique in a page, you should not repeat it.

Comment: I considered that possibility. I guess you should never have too much pride to check the basic stuff. Ah, well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css should be like this:

```
#centerBox {
    margin:auto;
    width:60%;
    height:1200px;
    background-color:#D6D1F9;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.centerText {
    font-size:140%;
    font-color:#000000;
    font-family:courier;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

because in your html page centerBox is id (#) and centerText is class (.)

[code is given here ( demo )](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWxaXZ?editors=110)